# Docky: No menu effects on LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, themes, lxde, docky

When I was using LXDE I realized there was no menu animations in the Docky. Then I got this message:
[image: (docky needs the desktop effects enabled to work properly. some options are disabled and themes and animations will appear "incorrectly" says the balloon in the upper right corner of the screen)]
(docky needs the desktop effects enabled to work properly. some options are disabled and themes and animations will appear "incorrectly" says the balloon in the upper right corner of the screen) those desktop effects are enabled so what is going on?
(yes I am aware Docky works properly with GNOME but it's also compatible with lxde)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `xcompmgr`

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr
```

Now add the command `xcompmgr -n` to autostart

If this does not work, you can try installing `compton`.

```
sudo apt-get install compton
```

Now, restart your computer, run docky and use the following command to start `compton`

```
@compton -c -r 16 -l -24 -t -12 -G -b
```

(If this does not work, try running `compton -c -r 16 -l -24 -t -12 -G -b && exit`)

To add compton to startup applications, open terminal, and run the command

`sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

Then add the line `@compton -c -r 16 -l -24 -t -12 -G -b`

Comment: installed it, didn't work

Comment: What happens when you run the command `xcompmgr -n` in terminal when docky is running?

Comment: it kills docky and it pops up again but there's still no animation

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it

Comment: Well compton is more maintained than xcompmgr I am pretty sure.  Although shouldn't you not add xcompmgr and compton both at once.

Comment: Well I never used Compton personally, and xcompmgr did not work for OP. So I edited my answer to "try Compton if xcompmgr does not work"